# Drawing.Graphics - Way to change pixel offset of source bitmap?

Tags: .net, vb.net, drawimage

Having a small problem finding a function or method to do what I'm looking for, hoping someone might be able to give a bit of insight here.

I've got a function that's supposed to extract and return a 32x32px bitmap from a larger bitmap which has a set of 32x32 tiles inside it.

Here's the code I have now, but it's wrong since the `Tile.GFX_Pos` properties are telling it where in the destination image to draw, not where in the source image to draw from.

```
  Overloads Shared Function TileGFX(ByVal SrcGFX As Bitmap, ByVal Tile As TileDef) As System.Drawing.Bitmap
      Try
          Dim GFX As Bitmap = TileBitmap()
          Dim GGFX As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(GFX)
          GGFX.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(SrcGFX, New Rectangle(Tile.GFXXPos, Tile.GFXYPos, TileSize, TileSize))

          Return GFX
      Catch ex As Exception
          Return TileBitmap()
      End Try
  End Function
```

So since this doesn't work, what I'm wondering is if anyone knows a good way to select where in the `SrcGFX` bitmap to blit from, instead of (as currently and incorrectly) selecting where in the destination bitmap to blit to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DrawImage()` method instead of `DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped()`.
`DrawImage` has umpteen billion overloads (ok, 30) including a bunch that let you specify both the source and destination locations.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  I didn't see that overload before!